# Java: NullPointerException in Jframe when hiding buttons

Tags: java

I am working on a quiz for a school assignment and i am attempting to create a GUI using JFrame. I had an idea to make all the buttons invisible and only appear after clicking the start button. However when I attempted to do so by using the .setVisible(false) command in the main method, it gives me a nullpointerexception. I am unsure about whats wrong and I am hoping someone could give me some pointers. Here's my code:

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class QuizGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form QuizGUI
 */
public QuizGUI() {
    initComponents();
}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Q1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Q2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Q3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Q4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Q5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Bonus = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Exit = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Start = new javax.swing.JButton();
    EndQuiz = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Timer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jButton4.setText("jButton4");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Q1.setText("Question 1");
    Q1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            Q1StateChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    Q1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Q1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addComponent(Q1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Q1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11))
    );

    Q1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Question1");

    Q2.setText("Question 2");
    Q2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Q2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Q2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 146, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(13, 13, 13)
            .addComponent(Q2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    Q2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Question2");

    Q3.setText("Question 3");
    Q3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Q3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Q3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(Q3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    Q3.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Question3");

    Q4.setText("Question 4");
    Q4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Q4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Q4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(13, 13, 13)
            .addComponent(Q4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    Q4.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Question4\n");

    Q5.setText("Question 5");
    Q5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Q5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
    jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
    jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addComponent(Q5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(13, 13, 13)
            .addComponent(Q5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    Q5.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Question5");

    Bonus.setText("Bonus");
    Bonus.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BonusActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel7Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel7);
    jPanel7.setLayout(jPanel7Layout);
    jPanel7Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(9, 9, 9)
            .addComponent(Bonus)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel7Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(Bonus)
            .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    Exit.setText("Exit");
    Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Vivaldi", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Quiz");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 35)); // NOI18N

    Start.setText("Start");
    Start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StartActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
    jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
    jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(Start)
            .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(Start)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    EndQuiz.setText("End Quiz");
    EndQuiz.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            EndQuizActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Timer.setText("jLabel3");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(73, 73, 73)
            .addComponent(EndQuiz)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 92, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Exit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(116, 116, 116))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Timer)
                    .addGap(71, 71, 71))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(EndQuiz)
                    .addGap(56, 56, 56))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                            .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jPanel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(Exit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Timer)
                            .addGap(168, 168, 168))))))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void Q1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                               

private void Q1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Q1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( //Question 1
             null,
             Question.getQuestionMCQ(1),
             "Q1",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
             null,
             Question.Options(0),
             Question.Options(0)[1]
              ); 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             Question.checkAnswerMCQ (Q1,1));    

    if (Question.getScore()<1) {
        jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.getScore()));
        Q2.setVisible(true); //Q1
    }
    else {}
}                                  

private void Q2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Q2 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( //Question 2
             null,
             Question.getQuestionMCQ(2),
             "Q2",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
             null,
             Question.Options(1),
             Question.Options(1)[1]
              );

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             Question.checkAnswerMCQ (Q2,2));

    if (Question.getScore()<2) {
        jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.getScore()));
        Q3.setVisible(true); //Q2
    }
    else {}
}                                  

private void Q3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Q3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             null,
             Question.getQuestionOE(1),
             "Q3",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             Question.checkAnswerOE(Q3, 1));

    if (Question.getScore() <3) {
        jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.getScore()));
        Q4.setVisible(true); //Q3
    }
    else {}
}                                  

private void Q4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Q4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             null,
             Question.getQuestionOE(2),
             "Q4",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             Question.checkAnswerOE(Q4, 2));

    if (Question.getScore() < 4) {
        jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.getScore()));
        Q5.setVisible(true); //Q4
    }
    else {}
}                                  

private void Q5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Q5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             null,
             Question.getQuestionOE(3),
             "Q5",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             Question.checkAnswerOE(Q5, 3));

             if (Question.getScore() < 5) {
     jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.getScore()));  
     EndQuiz.setVisible(true);
             }
             else if (Question.getScore()==5) {
         Bonus.setVisible(true);
     }
     else {}
}                                  

private void BonusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    BonusButtonPicture s =new BonusButtonPicture();
    s.setVisible(true);
}                                     

private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}                                    

private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.restartScore()));
     Q1.setVisible(true);
     Start.setVisible(false);
}                                     

private void EndQuizActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for taking the quiz! You have acheived a score of " +Question.getScore());

         int retry = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to take the quiz again?");

         switch (retry) { 
         case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:  //ends the program
                                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"End of quiz");
                                     System.exit(0);
                                     break;

         case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION: jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(Question.restartScore())); //restarts 
                                                                Question.randomizeQuestionsMCQ();
                                                                Question.randomizeQuestionsOpenEnded();
                                                                Start.setVisible(true);
                                     break;

         case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION: System.exit(0); //closes the program
     }
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
     Question.randomizeQuestionsMCQ();
     Question.randomizeQuestionsOpenEnded();
     /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new QuizGUI().setVisible(true);
     });

     Q1.setVisible(false);
     Q2.setVisible(false);
     Q3.setVisible(false);
     Q4.setVisible(false);
     Q5.setVisible(false);
     Bonus.setVisible(false);
     EndQuiz.setVisible(false);
     }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private static javax.swing.JButton Bonus;
private static javax.swing.JButton EndQuiz;
private javax.swing.JButton Exit;
private static javax.swing.JButton Q1;
private static javax.swing.JButton Q2;
private static javax.swing.JButton Q3;
private static javax.swing.JButton Q4;
private static javax.swing.JButton Q5;
private static javax.swing.JButton Start;
private static javax.swing.JLabel Timer;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private static javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel7;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

The error appears in the main method

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
   //code

     Q1.setVisible(false); //Error here
     Q2.setVisible(false);
     Q3.setVisible(false);
     Q4.setVisible(false);
     Q5.setVisible(false);
     Bonus.setVisible(false);
     EndQuiz.setVisible(false);
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the buttons inside the constructor of your class which is called after the

```
 Q1.setVisible(false);
 Q2.setVisible(false);
 Q3.setVisible(false);
 Q4.setVisible(false);
 Q5.setVisible(false);
 Bonus.setVisible(false);
 EndQuiz.setVisible(false);
```

part of code which causes the exception. What you need to do is include this snippet inside

```
/* Create and display the form */
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    new QuizGUI().setVisible(true);
 });
```

and it should be OK.